# Unable to Update UI using LiveData and Room

Tags: java, android, android-room, android-livedata

I am writing and reading to a local SQLite database using `Room` and `LiveData`. I have successfully read and wrote to the database, as I am using `Stetho` to confirm.

I understand `LiveData` handles functionality on a separate thread. I am struggling with updating my `RecyclerView` based on the database information I retrieve using `LiveData`:

```
    private void retrieveTasks() {
    final LiveData<List<Movie>> movies = mDb.movieDao().loadAllMovies();
    movies.observe(this, new Observer<List<Movie>>() {
        @Override
        public void onChanged(@Nullable List<Movie> movies) {
            for (Movie movie : movies) {
                String photoURL = "http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w185" + movie.getPoster_path();
                Log.v("FAVORITE_URL", photoURL);
                mMovieURLS.add(photoURL);
            }
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    mMovieResultsAdapter.swapDataSet(mMovieURLS);
                    mMovieResultsAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            });

        }
    });
}
```

Comment: `onChanged()` will be called on the main application thread; you do not need `runOnUiThread()`. Beyond that, what exactly do you mean by "I am struggling with updating my RecyclerView based on the database information I retrieve using LiveData"? Are you getting compile errors? Are you getting runtime errors? Is the `onChanged()` method being called?

Comment: @CommonsWare onChanged is being called because I have a log in there so I can verify; the RecyclerView simply is not updating. It may not have to do with threading then. What other code do you need to see? I can post or alternatively: https://github.com/troy21688/PopularMovies

Comment: Perhaps there are issues in your `swapDataSet()` implementation. You might step through that code and see what is going on.

Comment: Interesting, it is within my RecyclerView adapter and I simply change the dataset. I wonder if since it is within the Adapter class, it is causing problems:         ```public void swapDataSet(ArrayList<String> dataset) {
            mMovieURLS = dataset;

        }```